# ajax jquery form stopped sending emails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form which was sending emails from the server before but all of a sudden it stopped working. I cant seem to figure out the issue. When I use the form without ajax then email works perfectly. I saw http 200 code in the dev tools and no errors. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

html:

```
<form id="form1" class="form-action" action="" method="POST">

        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class = "name" required />
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  required />
        <input type="text" name='company' id="company" class="company" required />
        <textarea class= "message" name="message" id="message" required /> 
        </textarea>


<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="x" data-callback="recaptcha"></div>


     <button type="submit" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
     <span class="success_message font-weight-bolder text-center hide" style="margin-left: 30px;">
                                            message received.</span>
</form>
<script>
function reset_form(){
        $("#form1")[0].reset();
    }
    function reset_success_message(){
        $('.success_message').addClass('hide');
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#name').click(function () {
            $('.success_message').addClass('hide');
        });
        $('.email').click(function () {
            $('.success_message').addClass('hide');
        });
        $('.company').click(function () {
            $('.success_message').addClass('hide');
        });
        $('#message').click(function () {
            $('.success_message').addClass('hide');
        });

        $('#form1').submit(function (e) {
            $('.success_message').addClass('hide');
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
               url: 'serverside.php',
               type: 'post',
               data: $('#form1').serialize(),
               success: function (response) {
                    if(response == 'submitted'){
                        reset_form();
                        $('.success_message').removeClass('hide');

                    }
               }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

serverside.php

```
<?php

$email_to = 'x@domain.com';
$email_subject = 'form submission';
$email = $_POST ['email'];

$required = array('name','email','company', 'message');


$form1_complete = FALSE;

$validation = array();

if(!empty($_POST)) {

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = remove_email_injection(trim($value));

    foreach($required as $field) {

        if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) array_push($validation, $field);

        if($_POST[$field] == '') array_push($validation, $field);

        if($field == 'email') if(!validate_email_address($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);
    }

    if(count($validation) == 0) {
        $email_content = 'New Comment: ' . "\n\n";

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'submit') $email_content .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\n\n ";
        }


        $recaptcha_secret = "x";
        $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$recaptcha_secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        if($response["success"] === true) {

            mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_content, "From:" . $email);

         }
        else
        {
        }
       echo 'submitted';
    }
}

function validate_email_address($email = FALSE) {
    return (preg_match('/^[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i', $email))? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function remove_email_injection($field = FALSE) {
    return (str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:"), '', $field));
}

?>
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Try checking the result of the `mail()` function. Check your mail server log.

Comment: @Barmar thank you so much for your reply. i just checked and found out that i dont have access to that log. will ask hosting provider for that. actually i didnt even know  there is a log file, thank you for that info. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the Recaptcha secrets. Removing the Recaptcha if condition it works fine.

[image]

```
<?php

    $email_to = 'ahmed_rises@hotmail.com'; //-----------> Invalid Email Id was added here
    $email_subject = 'form submission';
    $email = $_POST ['email'];

    $required = array('name','email','company', 'message');


    $form1_complete = FALSE;

    $validation = array();

    if(!empty($_POST)) {

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = remove_email_injection(trim($value));

        foreach($required as $field) {

            if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) array_push($validation, $field);

            if($_POST[$field] == '') array_push($validation, $field);

            if($field == 'email') if(!validate_email_address($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);
        }

        if(count($validation) == 0) {
            $email_content = 'New Comment: ' . "\n\n";

            foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
                if($key != 'submit') $email_content .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\n\n ";
            }

            //Recaptca Secrets are Missing?????? Random string passed!
            $recaptcha_secret = "x";

            $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret="
            .$recaptcha_secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']); //-----> Also Recapta response from
            //the form is also missing since there its not working and neither getting passed

            $response = json_decode($response, true);

            //Printed the Output in which it shows the recapta Error
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($response);

            //If you ae to remove the Recapta Condition, the mail will be send!
            // if($response["success"] === true) {
                echo "==========";

                echo "email_subject:".$email_subject.", email:".$email.",email_to:".$email_to;
                mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_content, "From:" . $email);

                echo "==========";

            // }
            // else
            // {
            //     echo "Failed";
            // }

            echo "<br>";
            echo 'submitted';
        }
    }

    function validate_email_address($email = FALSE) {
        return (preg_match('/^[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i', $email))? TRUE : FALSE;
    }

    function remove_email_injection($field = FALSE) {
        return (str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:"), '', $field));
    }

?>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That was it :)  I couldnt figure out what was wrong and never thought about captcha, i just tested with what you did and worked perfectly. thank you so much !!!! Is there a way to add a working if condition ? when i use the form without ajax, the mail is getting sent with exact if condition i have now. Thank you again, i was going insane. :) @Mr

Comment: No problem! happy to help. Yes you can send Recaptcha without ajax. Just add the php file path in the form action attribute, the rest will work as it is. The $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] will get the response but first you have to get Recaptcha working . For that, you have to add the recaptcha key from here:
http://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin
After logining in, you will get a key and you have to place it in data-sitekey in place of x:
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="x" data-callback="recaptcha"></div>

and in php code as well in here:

 $recaptcha_secret = "x";

Comment: recaptcha is working. I have captcha key and secret both in main server file. in here i just put "x".  i want to have captcha verifying secret in server side too.  at this moment that "if condition" is not working. without that mail is sent. @Mr

Comment: Its working, I inserted the recaptcha key and i am able to recevie the response on the server side
 $recaptcha_secret = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe";

            $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret="
            .$recaptcha_secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']); 
            $response = json_decode($response, true);

Comment: i tested same code in hostgator and bluehost. both not sending emails. when i take out "captcha if condition" like you said, i get email from both hosting.  is there a different way to write that condition ? thank you for your time and help :) @Mr

Comment: print_r($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) use this on server side and check what value is printing

Comment: i replaced couple of code, i had $response = json_decode($response, true);
        if($response["success"] === true) {  and i removed true condition and used if($response->success) instead. started working. :) i have no idea why.  without your help i would have never found out where the main issue was and how to properly debug. i really appreciate your time and help. :) @Mr

Comment: No problem! Happy to help :). if you found it helpful,do vote me up.